# rewriterule not working

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

I have post type `example` with 2 records: `exam1` and `exam2`. This post type was created by plugin `Types Toolset` (`www.wp-types.com`). So link to `exam1` looks like `my_site/example/exam1`. Also I have 1 GET-parameter: `my_site/example/exam1?get=param`.
What I need. I need to rewrite URL from `my_site/example/exam1?get=param` to `my_site/param/exam1`. I wrote this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(exam1|exam2)/([^/]+)/?$ /example/$2/?get=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the right rule. It should work. But it does not work. When I go to the `my_site/param/exam1` , it redirects to `my_site/example/exam1`. 
I know that it is `redirect_canonical`. And I can remove it:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

But my RewriteRule still not working - no redirects from `my_site/example/exam1?get=param` to `my_site/param/exam1`.
Why? Please help me. I need it very much.

Comment: Have you thought about flushing the rewrite rule cache?

Answer (score 1):

### Terminology

I think you have some terminology a little mixed up:

- A URL "rewrite" alters the endpoint of a HTTP request. If `http://example.com/param/exam1` really serves content from `http://example.com/examples/exam1?get=param`, then the former is being rewritten to the latter (though not necessarily visible to the end-user).
- In the world of URL-rewriting, a "redirect" is a rewrite that (instead of serving the request from the altered endpoint) kicks back a HTTP `300`-range status code, telling the client that sent the HTTP request to send a new request to the rewritten URL (thus altering the address visible to the end-user). If a user enters `http://example.com/param/exam1` in their address bar, and then the browser is forwarded to `http://example.com/examples/exam1?get=param`, then the former will have been redirected to the latter.

---

### RewriteRule Analysis

At a glance, I would suspect that your `RewriteRule` is never matching your URLs; or if it is, not rewriting them as you might expect:

```
RewriteRule ^(exam1|exam2)/([^/]+)/?$ /example/$2/?get=$1 [QSA,L]
```

- Match HTTP request paths:

  - `^(exam1|exam2)/`: **beginning** with `exam1/` or `exam2/` and capture `exam1`/`exam2` as sub-group `$1`...
  - `([^/]+)`: ...followed by 1 or more non-`/` characters, which will captured as sub-group `$2`...
  - `/?$`: ...possibly followed by a `/` at the **very end**.
- Redirect matched request paths to `/example/$2/?get=$1`

In practice:

- A request sent to `http://example.com/param/exam1` will not be rewritten as the request path begins with `param/` and not `exam1/` or `exam2/`
- A request to `http://example.com/exam1/param/` will be rewritten to be served by the endpoint `http://example.com/example/param/?get=exam1`
- A request to `http://example.com/exam1/param/test` will not be rewritten because the request path does not end at the first path segment after `exam1` or `exam2`

---

### Solution

To rewrite the URL you've specified, you need to swap the capture groups in your Regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(exam1|exam2)/?$ /example/$2/?get=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will match path segments in the desired order and correct your back-references. However, this rule comes with some strange caveats that could cause unexpected behaviors. In practice, requests to:

- `http://example.com/foo/exam1` => `http://example.com/example/exam1?get=foo`
- `http://example.com/bar/exam1/` => `http://example.com/example/exam1?get=bar`
- **`http://example.com/posts/exam2_announcement` => `http://example.com/example/exam2?get=posts`**
- **`http://example.com/tests/exam120` => `http://example.com/example/exam1?get=tests`**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to handle this in WordPress using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Drop this in **functions.php** or a **plugin**. It's longer than a simple `ReWriteRule` but you'll have a little more flexibility and control on the WordPress side.

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'ExamRewrite' ) ):

    class ExamRewrite {
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM = '__redirect_exam';

        // WordPress hooks
        public function init() {
            add_filter( 'query_vars', array ( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'parse_request', array ( $this, 'sniff_requests' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'add_endpoint' ), 0 );
        }

        // Add public query vars
        public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
            $vars[] = static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM;
            $vars[] = 'get';
            $vars[] = 'exam';
            return $vars;
        }

        // Add Endpoint
        public function add_endpoint() {
            add_rewrite_rule( '^example/(exam1|exam2)', 'index.php?' . static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM . '=1&exam=$matches[1]', 'top' );
            //////////////////////////////////
            flush_rewrite_rules( false ); //// <---------- REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE
        }

        // Sniff Requests
        public function sniff_requests( $wp_query ) {
            global $wp;

            if ( isset(
                $wp->query_vars[ static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM ],
                $wp->query_vars[ 'get' ] ) ) {
                $get     = $wp->query_vars[ 'get' ];
                $exam    = $wp->query_vars[ 'exam' ];
                $new_url = site_url( "/$get/$exam" );
                wp_safe_redirect( $new_url, 301 );
                die();
            }
        }
    }

    $wpExamRewrite = new ExamRewrite();
    $wpExamRewrite->init();

endif; // ExamRewrite
```